# Unable to create azure bot service using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

I am trying to create a bot service using command New-AzureRmResource

i have a resourcegroup create - testRG

properties:

```
@{
    Location = "global"
    Properties        = @{
    MsaAppId = <<appid>>}
    ResourceName   = "test"
    ResourceType   = "Microsoft.BotService/botServices/"
    ResourceGroupName = "testRG"
    Force             = $true
}
```

but i keep getting the following error:

```
InvalidBotData : Name: Name is required.
```

I tried adding 'Name' field to properties but that fails with the same error

I also tried using **New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment** with same details in my template file but i get the same error:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 1:33:48 PM - Resource Microsoft.BotService/botServices '...' failed with message 
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidBotData",
        "message": "Name: Name is required. "
    }
}
```

how can I directly create a bot service using powershell/any other scripting language without having to go to azure portal?

Comment: Are you setting the -Properties as hashtable? It says here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/new-azurermresource?view=azurermps-6.5.0) it expects a PSObject.

Comment: @Theo `PSObject` is the `object` of powershell.  It's a generic that could take anything.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1  I think the function is not expecting a property called **Name**, but it wants to find the NAMES of the properties. The OP shows Hashtable and the docs say that `New-AzureRmResource` expects a **PSObject** in its `-Properties`. I think it enumerates the names/values of the properties like with `$obj.PSObject.Properties`. A PSObject has **Name** and **Value**. A Hastable uses **Key** and **Value**. Hence perhaps the criptic error message. Wouldn't hurt to try `$psProps = New-Object PSObject -Property @{...}` and use this with `New-AzureRmResource -Properties $psProps ...`

Answer (score 1):

You could [use azure CLI to create a bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tools-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-3.0). Enable the Azure CLI bot extension and create a new bot.

Please refer to the command below.

```
az bot create --resource-group "my-resource-group" --name "my-bot-name" --kind "my-resource-type" --description "description-of-my-bot"
```

I use the command to create a web type bot, it works fine on my side.

[image]

Check it in the portal.

[image]
For more details about the properties, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/botservice/bot?view=azure-cli-latest#ext-botservice-az-bot-create).